# select 1 row(latest or oldest) if there are two records that are within a second

Tags: sql, oracle

**My data looks like below :**

If there are two records that are within a second window and the DML_TYPE is not equal(example rows:(5,6), (7,8), (9,10)),  return only 1 record(either DML_TYPE = "U"(5,7,9) or DML_TYPE="I"(6,8,10)).

**Looking for standard sql(not vendor specific)  query that should return rows :**

```
 1,2,3,4,5,7,9
    or
    1,2,3,4,6,8,10
```

**what i have tried so far :**  This returns all rows.

```
select coh.contractor_order_hid, coh.change_time, coh.DML_TYPE
from contractor_order_hist coh
join contractor_order_hist cohSOCN on coh.contractor_order_hid = cohSOCN.contractor_order_hid
where extract( day from(coh.change_time - cohSOCN.change_time)*24*60*60) < 1 and coh.dml_type != coh.dml_type;
```

thanks for your help in advance.

[image]

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) What if there are three records?  What if there are 10 records half a second apart?

Comment: @Gordon update tag with oracle. If it is 2, 10 or 1000 records that fall within a second window, randomly get one doesn't really matter. But Given our system there will be only 2 (1 with DML type "U" and other with "I")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select coh.*
from (select coh.*,
             lag(change_time) over (order by change_time) as prev_change_time,
             lag(dml_type) over (order by dml_type) as prev_dml_type
      from contractor_order_hist coh
     ) coh
where prev_change_time is null or
      prev_change_time < change_time - interval '1' second or
      prev_dml_type = dml_type or
      prev_cml_type is null;
```